# Maximum no of objects in PDF

Tags: pdf

What are the maximum no of objects that a PDF file can have?

Comment: Clarify, how are you attacking this?

Comment: The PDf file internally consists of objects. Just wanted to know if there is any limitation on the Max no of objects a pdf file can have?

Comment: Attacking? i want to natively parse the PDF file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the PDF specifications:

> In general, PDF does not restrict the size or quantity of things described in the file
>   format, such as numbers, arrays, images, and so on.

....

> PDF itself has one architectural limit. Because ten digits are allocated to byte
>   offsets, the size of a file is limited to 10
>   10
>   bytes (approximately 10GB)."

Comment: From Spec:
Entries in the file trailer dictionary
Size: Integer: The Total no of entries in the file Cross Ref table.
Here i am confused if this define the limitation  as 2 byte integer "65535" for no of objects. I am not sure.

Comment: It's actually 10 digits: 0000000000-9999999999, and from what I undetstand PDF uses two more keys for the cross-reference. The second key is 5 digits.

Comment: @Tommy: The second 'key' designates the *generation* of an object. It is useful in tracking changes to a file. Once the generation reaches 65535, the object shall no longer be reused, and a new object slot needs to be allocated. This doesn't impose a limit in itself, though.